# Dell precision 5760 + wd19tbs dock only shows 4K@30hz on HDMI

Tags: display, hdmi, 4k-monitor

I have a Dell precision 5760 laptop, installed ubuntu 22.04, Nvidia driver is version 510.
I connected my TV to wd19tbs dock HDMI port, and it can only dispaly max to 4K@30hz.
While same hardware on Windows11, the TV can display 4K@60Hz, which shows all hardware has capability.
Here's xrandr output, you can see with 4K resolution, only support to 30Hz

```
DP-1-1 connected 7680x4320+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 708mm x 398mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +  50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   3840x2160     30.00*   25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1280x1024     75.02  
   1360x768      60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Welcome any help.

thanks,
Leslie

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved by switching to wayland from x11, now it can display 4K@60Hz on my TV

Comment: This solution causes another issue, wayland has blurry problem on fractional scaling, so I have to disable fractional scaling and leave my 1080p monitor with 200% scaling

Answer (score 0):

Found another solution, I disabled Intel integrated graphics card in BIOS, then x11 can display 4K@60Hz on TV now.
It looks even I used prime-select to choose nvidia, x11 still using iGPU behind for some cases. But wayland doesn't have this behavior.